# Error at the beginner_tutorials package - build error (ROS tutorials)

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am a beginner at ROS and I was doing the following tutorial :
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29 .

I did exactly what the tutorial instructed me to do (copy - pasted the code in use) and then tried to build my project
with catkin_make .I also checked the directories of the package and everything was in accordance to the tutorial's instructions .I also sourced every environmental variable needed .I am in 14.04 Ubuntu LTS (dual install with windows) .

However, I got the following errors  :

```
/opt/ros/jade/include/ros/time.h:180:31:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:248:84: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::io::too_many_args::too_many_args(int&, int&)’
                 boost::throw_exception(too_many_args(self.cur_arg_, self.num_args_)); 
                                                                                    ^
/usr/include/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:248:84: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/format.hpp:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/jade/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/jade/include/ros/serialization.h:34,
                 from /opt/ros/jade/include/std_msgs/String.h:14,
                 from /home/patrchri/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/talker.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/format/exceptions.hpp:66:15: note: boost::io::too_many_args::too_many_args()
         class too_many_args : public format_error
               ^
/usr/include/boost/format/exceptions.hpp:66:15: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/boost/format/exceptions.hpp:66:15: note: boost::io::too_many_args::too_many_args(const boost::io::too_many_args&)
/usr/include/boost/format/exceptions.hpp:66:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/src/talker.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Could you please tell me what I am missing here and what this error means?
In case more info is needed for you to help me, please tell me to edit my question .

Thank you in advance for your help .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233151/error-at-the-beginner_tutorials-package---build-error-(ros-tutorials)/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-28**:
This output just shows that there is an error, but not which one.
Scroll up in the terminal and please post the real error message.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-04-28**:
What OS are you on? What version of boost do you have installed on your system?

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-04-28**:
I am in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-04-29**:
I found the error .Thank you for your help anyway :)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-29**:
@patrchri we typically don't close questions on ROS answers. If you figured this out, maybe you could answer your own question, so others can find this solution?

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-04-29**:
@mig I need more points to reopen the question so I will answer it here .I apologize for closing it without posting the solution, but it was not something major .Due to character's limitations the answer is posted at my next comment .

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-04-29**:
The error was generated because of bad mistyping of the "ros/ros.h" inclusion .This happened because at start I attempted to write the code and then copy pasted the rest of the code .The strange part is that the terminal didn't indicate me the error at the file.cpp .Thanks again for your answers .

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-29**:
@patrchri, open now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was generated because of bad mistyping of the `#include "ros/ros.h"` statement .This happened because at start I attempted to write the code on my own, but then I decided to copy paste the rest of the code .This wrong copy paste led to a `ros.h"` statement instead of the proper inclusion as written above .The strange part is that the terminal didn't indicate me the error at the file.cpp as a syntax error ,as there was no `#include` statement .

Thanks again for your answers .

The wrong syntax was like that :

```
ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <sstream>

(The rest of the code in talker.cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1